# Programmatically know which .NET textbox to use? Multiple Textboxes with number attached to the end

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a game I'm making in .NET at the moment. Right now I have something like this for determining which textbox belongs to which player:

```
switch(player.ID) {
    case 1: storeRandPlayerInfo = textbox1.Text;
    break;
    case 2: storeRandPlayerInfo = textbox2.Text;
    break;
    case 3: storeRandPlayerInfo = textbox3.Text;
    break;
}
```

My question is, is there a way to do something like Windows.Textbox["textbox"+player.ID].Text; Know what i mean? I can't find anything online so I assume it's not possible but I just wanted to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely there is a way. One of them is:

```
// define and init
TextBox[] playerBoxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };

// use 
storeRandPlayerInfo = playerBoxes[player.ID - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of this, I'm pretty sure I've used this technique before.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
private TextBox GetPlayerTextBox(int playerId)
        {
            string textBoxName = string.Format("TextBox{0}", playerId);
            return this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(t => t.Name == textBoxName).Single();
        }
```

Comment: This way your design is very flexible. There just needs to be a naming convention for the textboxes, based on player number etc..

Comment: There is no need for so much LINQ here.

Comment: I think this adds a lot of flexibility, and sets you up well if you have many players. BTW it's a one line statement with one condition :-)

Comment: Yes but seeing as this.Controls can be directly indexed by name, there is no need to iterate every single control each time to find the one you're looking for. See my answer.

Comment: Well, the controls can be wrapped in a panel. I think the performance hit is not even noticeable at that point. I used this.Controls just as an example. Your ".Contains(key)" will still have to do a similar scan of the collection as it's not a hashtable

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the indexing of "this.Controls" (point to note, "this.Controls" will only contain the top level controls on the form, controls within a groupBox for instance will be in a collection in "this.groupBox1.Controls", so index into that collection rather than "this.Controls")

```
    private TextBox getPlayersBox(int player)
    {
        string expected = "textBox" + player.ToString();
        if (this.Controls.ContainsKey(expected))
            return this.Controls[expected] as TextBox;
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Not at all. This is the kind of logic maps were created for. LINQ generates unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a dictionary; you are describing a mapping, and that's what dictionaries do best. You can do it either with your ID, or the objects themselves:

```
// using ID as the key
private readonly Dictionary<int, TextBox> mPlayerTextBoxes;

// ...or using object as the key
private readonly Dictionary<Player, TextBox> mPlayerTextBoxes;

// in form constructor, after InitializeComponent call:

// using ID as the key
mPlayerTextBoxes = new Dictionary<int, TextBox>
{
   { player1.ID, textbox1 },
   { player2.ID, textbox2 },
   { player3.ID, textbox3 }
};

// using object as the key
mPlayerTextBoxes = new Dictionary<Player, TextBox>
{
   { player1, textbox1 },
   { player2, textbox2 },
   { player3, textbox3 }
};

// then when you want a textbox, given a player:
// using ID    
TextBox textBox = mPlayerTextBoxes[player.ID];

// using object
TextBox textBox = mPlayerTextBoxes[player];
```